# Advice on how to display a row of data on which calculation needed to be performed

Tags: python, django, django-models

Though this may be elementary but for me its proving beyond my level. And my thanks goes beforehand.

What I wanted to achieve is that a row of data which I am querying,and after querying on the basis of the value of the field in the Liveroute table being inactive I perform calculation of finding the distance between two sets of longitude and latitude values, I am able to use the haversine formula to calculate the distance between two points longitude and latitude. But what I am wary of that this calculation process may take time and I will not be able to display the data on time for larger number of rows in the table. So I thought I will save the result of calculation in another Table and fetch the data from that table and display it.

I will perform the calculation on a value in the table becoming inactive.
Here is the Django code which tells whether the row is active or inactive for a route in Liveroute model class.

```
class LiveRoutes(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User)
   route = models.ForeignKey(UserRoutes)
   status = models.ForeignKey(LiveRoutesStatus)
   traveller = models.ManyToManyField(LiveRouteTravellers)
   datetime = models.DateTimeField()

 def __unicode__(self):
    return self.route.__unicode__()

 def isActive(self):
   utc = pytz.utc
   os.environ['TZ'] = 'UTC'
   local = pytz.timezone("Asia/Calcutta")
   now = utc.localize(datetime.datetime.today())
   now = now.astimezone(local)
   time_delta = (local.localize(self.datetime.replace(tzinfo=None)) +    datetime.timedelta(minutes=self.route.journey_time_day)) - now
   if time_delta.days == -1 and (24 - (time_delta.seconds / 3600)) <= 2:
     return True
   elif time_delta.days >= 0:
     return True
   else:
     return False
```

Based on this value from isActive function I wanted to perform the calculation as follows

```
def carbonFootPrint(request):
if request.method != "GET":
   raise Http404

routes = LiveRoutes.objects.all();
routeDetailArr = []
for lroute in routes:
   routeDetail = dict()
   if lroute.isActive() == False:

      #Now I need to find out the start location and end location for the journey and the number of travellers. 
      routeDetail['travellers'] = lroute.traveller.all().count()
      routeDetail['start_loc_lat']= lroute.route.start_location.latitude
      routeDetail['start_loc_long'] = lroute.route.start_location.longitude
      routeDetail ['end_loc_lat'] = lroute.route.end_location.latitude
      routeDetail['end_loc_long'] =  lroute.route.end_location.longitude
      routeDetail['distance'] = haversine(start_loc_lat,start_loc_long,end_loc_lat,end_loc_long)
      routeDetailArr.append(routeDetail)
```

my problem is how to insert all this data back into another table, so that later on I could fetch those values.
Thanks any advice will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide me some link where that session thing is elaborated.

Comment: I don't have link but I can provide sample data.

Comment: Please anything of help will be thankfully received.

Comment: Django Sessions: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/

Answer (score 1):

In order to trigger the session, it must be like this:

```
request.session['travellers'] = lroute.traveller.all().count()
//other session here
```

To get and use the data, it must be:

```
travellers = request.session.get('travellers')
```

Comment: This will save the data in session. So that all along the session we will be able to use that data.Is this why you are suggesting me to use the session ?

I am just seeking clarification as I am new to web development.

Comment: But somehow I feel I dont need session support here. Let me explain further this Livroutes is about carpool application, so if a pool is over it should return inactive and then I gather all data related to that Liveroute and perform calculation and put it into another table. 
I want to trigger this calculation over the value in liveroute being inactive

Comment: You can do query filter inactive liveroute. You can perform the operation and get the data by id. It will calculate the data if there is no calculation for that live route. You can use if statement for that

Comment: have you try adding data in liveroute? your liveroute has many foreign keys, it will became complicated. Try to use "relate" in liveroute foreign keys